# Streaming large Datasets into smaller chunks in c#

Tags: c#, dataset

I frequently use large Datasets in a c# console application ( 1 million rows with around 30 odd columns) that I need to process in a sequential manner, these Datasets are first extracted from a remote database, I can't extract them in smaller chunks because the round trip over the wire would be too expensive.

What kind of options do I have in terms of breaking these into smaller chunks locally and reading it say, 10000 records at a time?.

I don't have a lot of RAM just around 2 GB or so, is there an efficient way for me to page these Datasets locally?.

Edit:
Would it make sense to serialize the DataTable or List and store it in a local NoSQL repository and then keep fetching 10000 records at a time?.

Comment: when you say "datasets" - do you mean `System.Data.DataSet` (or `DataTable`, etc) - or are you talking more abstractly, and the data is actually something like a `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` (an open reader), `T[]` etc for some `T`? It may matter, because of how `DataTable` is structured (the data in `DataTable` is stored in columns, not rows - which makes it expensive to partition horizontally)

Comment: it isn't entirely clear how the data is currently stored / accessed (after your extract step); this *also* may impact the answer; so: what is the data source currently? or is that still up for question?

Comment: When I say DataSet I mean System.Data.DataSet to be very precise, I am open to saving it in a different format though if that will speed up things.

Currently the DataSource is a stored procedure residing in a remote  SQL server, I can't page my records because the trip over the wire is rather expensive as my Database server and Application  servers are co-hosted in different locations.

I access the Datarow by iterating through the DataSet in a sequential manner using a "For" loop.

Comment: I have been wondering if it makes sense to store the DataSet in a local NOSQL database and then keep extracting just 10000 rows at a time or so, was wondering if that's even the right approach @MarcGravell

Comment: k; I'm still a bit confused here; you ask about splitting the data into chunks, but you say you can't do paging - but those two things are just two ways of saying the exact same thing. NoSQL vs a SQL database is an interesting question, but doesn't change all that much - you have the exact same issues in either case (plus: your existing ADO.NET tools won't love NOSQL). I'm pretty unclear what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve. Fetching batches of rows is very well understood; is that the issue? You mention the size / memory; is that the issue?

Comment: Either way - and I probably cant say this strongly enough - using `DataSet` / `DataTable` *almost certainly isn't helping you*;  as tools go, yes it will work, but it *almost always* isn't the most efficient way to do things. So if memory is your limiting factor, the first thing I would say is: stop using DataTable/DataSet.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I'm sorry that I wasn't able to make my problem statement clear. My problem is two fold.
1) I want to restrict the no of round trips to the remote database server.
2) I am not certain that looping through 1 million rows is a good solution.

I was looking at something like this, fetching the  data from the remote server, storing it whatever form is optimal ( serializing it into List<T> and storing it in a local key-value store ) and then looping through just 10,000 records at a time, that way the application doesn't need to keep all the records in memory.

Comment: I am open to saving it as List<T> instead of a DataTable, so that's not a problem, I could rewrite my code to do that, I am just wondering if there is a standard well recognized way of doing this, don't want to be re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: @MarcGravell, whilst moving from DataTable to List, do you think I could store it as a List of Dictionary items, because the column names are variable here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web application then you can enable "EnablePaging" attirbute of your data source control.

Comment: it isn't clear to me that this is answering the same question... or if it is: it is based on a *lot* of assumptions that aren't obvious from the question

Comment: No, it doesn't even address the same problem @MarcGravell, I hope my query is clearer, I made a few edits, apologies for not making it earlier.